# Is there a better way than static Instance Properties?

Tags: c#, static, singleton, instance

I'm very new to C# and currently I'm using this way to always use the same instance:

```
public class Sample{
    private Sample(){
        //initialize sth.
    }

    private static Sample _instance;
    public static Sample Instance{
        get{
            if(_instance == null)
                _instance = new Sample();
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know a better way because it doesnt seem quite object-orientated to me...

Comment: there are pro and cons. Without more context, the question has no sense. Please explain the kind of application you are building

Comment: It is a very broad subject. Search for Singleton Pattern and you will find numerous links. Here just one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: btw, the pattern you show is not thread-safe; you could get >1 different `Sample` instances

Comment: Summary:
[link](http://www.codingwithoutcomments.com/)
[link](http://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2009/11/22/singleton-considerations/)
"caching data (especially from a DB) use the proxy pattern to do this..." – ceretullis
Use Lazy<T> when using Singleton in Multithread environment
Use Dependency Injection to easily pass the Instance around and make unit testing comfortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is dependant on how you intend on using the property. Generally having a single static property across your full app is considered a *bad* idea as it can cause a lot of headaches when it comes to things like multi-threading environments/unit testing etc. However, there are scenarios where it is in-fact the correct approach e.g. logging.

Alternatively, you could use another approach where you pass the instance around to whoever needs it - more commonly know as [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: Finally, an answer that doesn't just provide yet-another-singleton-implementation. Other common problem scenarios would include unit-testing or multi-tenancy, (where in both cases you might find yourself suddenly needing isolated and different instances)

Comment: @MarcGravell I literally just updated my answer to mention unit testing as I realised I missed it! Yeah I think most people are too quick at jumping to code rather than actually assessing the design first.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK if you want to have a Singleton class. This kind of pattern is used to have only one instance of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this approach is perfectly valid. However, be careful with initializing the instance of the singleton in the `getter` of the `Instance` property -- especially if it takes a long time to create said object.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) and let the framework deal with the avoiding the race condition that your implementation yields.

```
private static Lazy<Sample> _instanceLazy = new Lazy<Sample>(() => new Sample());
public static Instance{get {return _instanceLazy.Value;} }
```

Definitely worth remembering that [singleton sucks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

Answer (score 0):

To create a Singleton, you can use multiple approaches.

If you write it explicitly, the best implementation method I found (nicely thread-safe) is:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.instance;
        }
    }

    class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

But another method is to use an Inversion of Control framework such as Unity or Castle Windsor, which you can then configure to treat your class as a singleton.

Comment: The code to write a singleton is much much simpler than that; what you show is a reasonable *lazily instantiated* singleton, though - which may be important if the cost of creating the singleton is important. In many cases, though, simply moving the readonly field up a level would be fine.